# I picked up the letter that was lying on the floor. Does it sound all right?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, perfect-constructions, past-continuous

Here's my context:

> *I entered the room and I saw a big heap of letters on the desk. One of them had fallen on the floor. I picked up the letter **lying** on
> the floor. / I picked up the letter **that was lying** on the floor
> and pitched it into the trash can.*

Or should it rather be "*had been lying* on the floor"?

Comment: You don't need lying at all. On the floor is enough.

Comment: Past Perfect ***had been lying*** is unlikely in this context for two reasons. Firstly, on purely *semantic* grounds, since the letter was ***still*** on the floor at the time it was referenced (where "had been" implies the letter might have been relocated somewhere else between lying on the floor and being picked up). Secondly (but arguably *more importantly*) we don't generally use Past Perfect in contexts where Simple Past is an acceptable alternative. Many non-native speakers overuse Past Perfect because it's easy to explain where it *can* be used (not the same as where it *must* be used).

Comment: Do you want to make your sentence correct, or do you want to know whether "lying" and "that was lying" are grammatically equivalent?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I thought the letter was no longer on the floor when I referenced it, as the first thing I mentioned was picking the letter up.

Comment: @gotube I rather want to clearly understand why I should use one tense or the other in similar contexts.

Comment: @Let Then yes, in this context, the two forms are grammatically equivalent, and as others have said, the shorter one is nearly always the best choice.

Comment: @gotube not sure what you mean. What do you think of what FumbleFingers said above about "had been lying" implying that the letter could have been relocated somewhere else between lying on the floor and being picked up?

Comment: @Let I meant "lying" and "that was lying" are equivalent in your example sentence. FF is correct on both points. I would add to their "*semantic grounds*" point that context would make it unlikely for someone to misinterpret it as if "the letter might have been relocated somewhere else", but yes, it could have that meaning.

Answer (score 1):

All versions are possible. However brevity is nearly always an advantage, so you could say

> I picked it up and threw it in the trash can.

You have already established that there was only one letter lying on the floor, so you don't need to repeat the information.

Comment: You haven't explicitly addressed OP's actual question (should it be Simple Past or Past Perfect?). But I'll upvote this simply because *brevity is nearly always an advantage* in this context pretty much amounts to ***use the simpler verb form***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In my defence the OP never actually mentioned any particular verb tense.  As an old engineer I just read it as a simple request, "What is the best way of saying this". But I take your point.

Comment: Not much of a defence, given the question highlights *[that was] **lying*** in cited text, and asks *should it rather be **had been lying***. But I've just realised that OP is implicitly asking which of plain adjectival ***lying*** and the finite verb clause ***that was lying*** should be preferred. In general I'm with you as regards favouring brevity, but I'm not necessarily convinced in that *exact* case. Explicitly "particularising" the letter with ***that was*** seems to me to make it stand out as more noticeable (both to the reader *and* the narrator), which may be stylistically better).

Comment: @PeterJennings Perhaps my sentences are a bit stilted, and thanks for pointing that out, but I'm rather more interested in whether I should have used "had been" in the context I provided.